# Date Calculation with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, date, calculated-columns

I'm making a dataset with pandas and wondering how to calculate the time lag between two different dates.
I've already got data "account_created_date" and "date_first_booking" both  showing the way like `2010-06-28`.
Could you tell me what the best way is to figure it out.
Your help greatly appreciated!

Here is a snap shot of some details.
I'd like to know how long has passed until "date_first_booking" since "account_created_date"

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A7UsL.jpg)

Comment: Show some sample data and expected output... please.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ thanks for your comment. just a little part of my data is uploaded. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can cast the date columns to `datetime` using `pd.to_datetime` if you have not already done so. Then the time elapsed is given by something like:

```
(df['date_first_booking']-df['account_created_date']).dt.days
```

Comment: thank you for your comment, but it comes out with an error.

Comment: I worked it out somehow on my own! such nice of you! thanks!!